# Can't Mount Phone, "according to mtab, /dev/sdb1 is already mounted on /"

Tags: mount, phone

My myTouch Slide wasn't mounting, so I decided to open Disk Utility. My phone shows up but when I click "Mount" it gives me this error:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdb1 is already mounted on /
mount failed
```

Here's my mtab:

```
/dev/sdb1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
none /var/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/matthew/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=matthew 0 0
/dev/sdg1 /media/Seagate\040GoFlex ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks 0 0
```

EDIT: Here's my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sda1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=3b0db205-2bdb-4c98-a506-6bdd3520d540 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: It will be very helpful if you also provide your /etc/fstab file

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make a specific entry for your phone in order to have it mount where you want it to mount. First, check what the UUID of the devices hooked up to your machine:

```
craig@lister:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for craig: 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="[long-string-of-hex-here]" TYPE="ext4"
...
```

That'll show you what the various UUIDs are for the filesystems on your machine. Then, you can add the device explicitly:

```
UUID=[long-string-of-hex-here] /mnt/phone  (and the rest of the mount line)
```

This may make life a little easier for you if your phone isn't showing up where you think it is. It also may clarify why your machine is trying to re-mount /dev/sdb1 when you click on your phone.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, now it's happening to my external HDD. So, following your instructions, I should add: " UUID="33c920a3-617f-4259-b6f7-c8b76bb68d71" " to my mtab?

Comment: I got that from what the terminal gave me: "/dev/sda1: LABEL="Seagate GoFlex" UUID="33c920a3-617f-4259-b6f7-c8b76bb68d71" TYPE="ext4" "

Comment: That should be to the fstab, not mtab.

Answer (score 0):

> Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
>   mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdb1 is already mounted on /
>   mount failed

Disk Utility reported error in Ubuntu 10.10 while mounting one of the drives

#### REASON

Your FSTAB file is incorrectly configured.
Your `/etc/mtab` and `/etc/fstab` files must be showing difference in mounted volumes entries. which is confusing for the "Disk Utility" to figure out on its own.

#### Example

In my case reinstalling Ubuntu 10.10 with auto partition option created the problem, leaving my Data Drive(IDE HDD) `/dev/sda` unreadable.
Ubuntu was installed at `/dev/sdb` (SATA HDD) but reported as `/dev/sda` in FSTAB, and I was unable to mount my 2nd HDD(Data Drive)

`/etc/mtab` contains the next line:

```
/dev/sdb1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0 0 0
```

Whereas '/etc/fstab' shows:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

#### Solution

You can change it manually, by changing your `/` partition entry to it's actual device name.

Find your `/` partition's actual device (eg. in my case `/dev/sdb1`)

1. Press ALT + F2 and run `gksudo gedit`.
2. Open up /etc/fstab
3. Change your root partition to the device listed in "Disk Utility".
4. Restart your computer, and enjoy

In my case I changed the next line from `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4    errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

to

```
/dev/sdb1 / ext4    errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Read about 'MTAB' & 'FSTAB' in wikipedia for more clarity...
Quite nicely explained there...Thanks Ton 2 all you guys @ Wikipedia.